# Possible combinations...

Tags: combinations

A friend has just shown me a question from his child's homework over which he's stumped (both child and father). Unfortunately I was unable to help as it stumped me, too. The question is...

There are...

4 starters

8 main meals

3 deserts

How many different 3 course meals can we make out of the above?

So how do we calculate the number of possible  meals?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you make independent choices, simply multiply the number of options for each course together, which gives $4\times 8 \times 3 = 96$.

Comment: Thanks. I just used a slightly more convoluted method and came up with the same answer. Didn't think it would be as easy as just multiplying the numbers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As JWeissman states, the total number of three course meals, assuming each includes one starter, one main, and one dessert, would be $4\cdot 8 \cdot 3=96$. This uses the fundamental principle of counting. To see why the formula works, you could try making a tree diagram or listing possible outcomes. For a smaller example, consider just 2 appetizers and 3 mains. Let the appetizers be A & B and let the mains be C, D, and E. The possible combinations are:
AC  BC
AD  BD
AE  BE
There are 2 choices for the first letter and 3 for the second, for a total of $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ choices.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a tree-like structure: take any option for the starter. There are 8 possible edges from it to main courses. For each main course there's an edge to 3 deserts. So for 1 starter you have 8*3 outcomes. And since you have 4 starters,  then...

Answer (score 1):

How many different 3 course meal we make out? Let's say the chief simply called it x,

Let's take an example of two starters {salad, pasta} and three meals{boeuf bourguignon, boeuf à la plancha,roti de boeuf}.

We can then take:
{salad,boeuf bourguignon},{salad, boeuf à la plancha}, {salad, roti de boeuf}
{pasta, boeuf bourguignon},{pasta, boeuf à la plancha}, {pasta, roti de boeuf}.
That it two say: two options

*(hum, yummy yummy, I can choose either the first, or the second)*

multiplied by three options

*(wohoho, miam miam! I can choose either the first starter with one of the three options or the second starter with one of the three options! that is to say six different things!)*

Generally speaking, there is always $x=\prod n_i$ with $n_i$ the number of things of one kind you may want to combine with the other $n_j$ things of other kind:

$$x=n_1*n_2*...*n_n$$

Hence the answer wich issimply multiply the number of options for each course together, which gives 4×8×3=... **(you tell me!)**